# pcap to Avro on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, pcap, avro

I need to know if there is any way where I can convert pcap file to avro , so that 
I can write map reduce program on avro data using hadoop ?

Otherwise what is the best practice when dealing with pcap files on hadoop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pcap file is a collection of records, each containing a time stamp, a packet length field, a "amount of data for that packet actually captured and saved" length field, and an unstructured blob of raw packet data.

The [Avro documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/) says:

> Avro provides:
>
> - Rich data structures.
>
> ....

"Unstructured blob of raw packet data" and "rich data structures" don't go together; you'll have to parse the raw packet data, the same way implementations of the protocols in the packet do and the same way tcpdump/Wireshark/various other protocol analyzers do, to turn it into structured data, so you can have data on which you can *do* processing.

So, first, you need to figure out what you're trying to do here.  What sort of analysis do you want to do?  What packet data do you want to process?  Packet time stamps?  Source and destination IP addresses?  Protocols within a packet?  Something in a particular protocol?

Comment: Thanks harris for the answer but I know the difference between pcap and avro file structures , and my question is how to convert pcap to avro format as we cant run map-reduce on pcap in hadoop. I'm dealing with TCP/IP protocol here , and few analysis which I will be able to do once I have the files in avro format !

Comment: Avro format isn't a format for packet data, it's "a data serialization system" for general data.  The only way to "convert pcap to avro format" would be to write code to take a pcap file record and structure it as a record containing a sub-record with the time stamp as int values for seconds and microseconds, the packet length as an int value, and the packet data as bytes.  And, yes, with the packet data as bytes, there will indeed be very few things you can analyze in that format.